# How to copy files from damaged HDD , skip individual files if takes too long in linux

Tags: hard-drive, bash, rsync, cp

I had a damaged HDD with very high value of Raw_Read_Error_Rate (50k!) but 0 for Reallocated_Sector_Ct , Reallocated_Event_Count, UDMA_CRC_Error_Count.

I have a directory with >1000 files that I want to recover. I tried:

1. cp *.* to newHDD. cp hang after a while.
2. rsync -av to newHDD, same hanging.
3. drag and copy with Thunar, same hanging.
4. tar damaged directory , same hanging.

But not all files are damaged, I try randomly copy some file, and it did successfully copied.

My question is if there anyway to copy a files and skip the process if it takes more than 2 mins? behavior like :

while "all files in a directory" {
do copy fileA { 
   if copying takes > n mins, skip, move on to next.
} done
}
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `rsync` with following options:

```
rsync --archive --update --verbose --delete --ignore-errors /path/source_folder/ /path/dest_folder/
```

**Path:**
`/path/source_folder/` - path to folder with damaged data
`/path/dest_folder/`   - path to folder where you save your data

**Options:**
`--archive` - archive mode
`--update`  - skip files that are newer on the receiver
`--verbose` - increase verbosity
`--delete`  - delete extraneous files from dest dirs (from folder where you save your data)
`--ignore-errors` - delete even if there are I/O errors

Please, first make test on testing folders and check result.

Comment: Also I'd like to recomend to use for your purposes utility `ddrescue`.

Comment: (1) I’m not sure `ignore-errors` is what the question asks for. (2) I don’t see a timeout.

Comment: (2) For looking timout and finish information you can add keys `--progress --stat`